# How to set filter for FileSystemWatcher for files without extention

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I´m watching a directory with 2 FileSystemWatcher(s).
FileSystemWatcher1 is looking for files named (file999) and FileSystemWatcher2 is looking for (file222) both without extention.
I know how to set the filter if there is a file like this - file222.txt, but in this case if I try to use file222.* is not working ...
How can I set the filter in this case? 
Thanks

Comment: why don't your files have extensions?

Comment: why can't you just use "file222" as the filter?

Comment: @Aniket , it is just the way the files are created ( is not up to me)

Comment: @shf301. Excellent !! I just thought that the extention was needed.. Thanks